# How to arrange points on a plane to minimize the maximum distance between any two of them?

Tags: geometry, optimization, discrete-geometry

> How to arrange n points on a plane such that the distance between any
>   two points is at least $1$ and the maximum of the distances between two
>   points is minimized?

It sounds like a world-famous problem, yet I can't find anything on the internet. I assume the answer is a $n-1$ sided regular polygon with one point in the center and the rest of them on the vertices, but I couldn't prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up circle packing.  Perhaps you want to pack them in a rouleax triangle, or in a circle.

Comment: The answer is known for $n\leq 13$ and for $n=19$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: @Empy2: It's not obvious to me why this should be equivalent to circle packing?

Comment: The points are surrounded by circles of radius $1/2$ that may not intersect because all distances are at least $1$.  The maximum distance on the other hand, I'm not sure it would be a large circle enclosing them.

Comment: @Empy2 But the circle packing problem minimizes the area you pack the circles in. It's not immediately obvious why should that also minimize the maximum distance.

Comment: Fair point. It's why I mentioned the Rouleaux triangle above.  But perhaps OP hadn't been looking at circle packing, which is certainly near the question asked.

Comment: It's not equivalent to packing circles in a circle.
Another way of phrasing the problem is
Minimizing the Ratio of Maximum to Minimum Distance
https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/maxmin/